# Gateway bridged mode

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, bridge

n00b question: I have a gateway from my ISP that lacks features and in order to access any advanced features whatsoever you must login to their site where settings are stored on their backend which creates a security concern as far as I'm concerned.

I would like to set the gateway into bridged mode but I want to setup 2 seperate networks with 2 seperate routers (for reasons) but while in bridge mode only 1 port is available.

I'm aware that a switch wouldn't work between the gateway bridge and router because it's a layer 2 or 3 device but would a hub work, seeing as how it's a layer 1 device? Or would this be a good use case for an edgerouter?

Edit: port forwarding isn't ideal due to what I mentioned at the beginning about options being hosted on ISP backend and not locally

Comment: Ask your ISP to provide Bridged Mode so you can add your own router with External WAN address and then your own internal stuff. I do that here and my Router (Cisco RVxx) provides the flexibility I need.

Comment: I can actually access bridge mode through the gateway but I was wondering if it's possible to connect 2 different routers to the bridge if I used a hub since it is a layer 1 device that simply repeats the signal? Sorry but my networking knowledge is quite basic.

Comment: The question is difficult to answer fully, because you're making some incorrect assumptions – switches aren't layer-3 devices, they work at layer-2. (*Routers*, on the other hand, are layer-3 devices.)

Comment: Use one router to service your needs and then attach the second one LAN to LAN.  I would keep it simple.

Comment: @user1686 sorry, you're correct, I will edit my question to reflect that but even still, slayer 2 device wouldn't work if I'm not mistaken (which I could be lol)

Comment: @John I thought about that as well but I'd like to avoid a double NAT and have 2 complete seperate networks... If possible.

Comment: Connecting two routers does not mean double-NAT. And more importantly, a router is not limited to having just one network.

Comment: @user1686 ok fair enough but my question is would a hub allow the bridged gateway to connect to 2 different hardware routers?

Comment: Two routers properly connected do not have a double NAT. Having two networks in a tiny environment like mine (and I think like yours) just causes complications. Everyone wants to print, for example. Bridged gateway (if I understand you) means two External IP addresses. More complication.

Comment: see if it's helpful to you:https://www.cyberciti.biz/networking/howto-connect-two-wireless-router-wirelessly-bridge-with-open-source-software/